# focus() method doesn't work while manually focusing with the mouse or tab key does

Tags: javascript, css

I try to focus an element of an email field [in this webpage](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/login?i=b3b848), with the following code:

```
document.querySelector("#user_email").focus();
```

While manual focusing with either clicking on the field with the mouse or using tab works, the `focus()` method fails to create the focus, as it seems both from the fact the CSS doesn't change, and the console returns "undefined".

As a newcomer, I ask why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digital Ocean's input boxes are focusing fine for me. The undefined basically means that nothing is returned from your expression. For example if you type `var a = 123` it'll still say undefined. Also there is no special CSS styling on these input boxes. You might be getting confused with the ones in their control panel.

**UPDATE:** OP was getting confused with Chromes default input styling.

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling `focus()` from console, focusing won't happen immediately - you have to go back to the site (close console). When you go back from console to a website by clicking on a website, focusing won't happen. Close console using shortcuts or use `setTimeout` to delay focusing to give you time to go back to the website.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with document.getElementById('user_email').

```js
document.getElementById('user_email').focus() ;
```

```html
<input id="user_email">
```

Comment: I still get the same result --- No CSS change and undefined in console.

Comment: Well the code is really simple and i can't see why it doesn't work : i tried in console in your site and no result with `document.getElementById('user_email').focus() ;`. Maybe it's because of something else... Can you try to remove, just for testing, your other JS code like `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/platform/1.3.4/platform.min.js` ?

Comment: This is not my site or my code and I don't have any other code running... :|

Comment: Well sorry can't help much more... Code is correct and work, you have an issue with anything else but if you can't edit rest of the code it's hard to help

Comment: Might it be some kind of defense mechanism the guys in DigitalOcean used? Or just a coding byproduct?